# How to Create Methods in Pharo

Tags: oop, smalltalk, pharo

I am am new to programming and currently learning Pharo Smalltalk. However, I got to a part of the book I am using (LearningOOP) and I am stuck at "Adding a setter method". The exercise is to write the method count: such that when invoked on an instance of Counter, instance variable is set to the argument given to the message. Can anyone help please?

```
|c|
c := Counter new count: 7
c count 7
>>>7
```

Answer (score 2):

In Counter class (instance side):

```
count: anInteger
   count := anInteger
```

Comment: Assuming that there is an inst var named 'count' in Counter class